# Mix task spawning a process does nothing

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I created a mix task which spawns a process. 
It uses `Flow`, reads from a stream and writes into a file defined in a `consumer`.

At the end of the day it just spawn some processes.

If I run it through `iex` it works fine as long as I leave the shell running.

But if I launch it from the command line as a mix task nothing happens, how do you leave the process opened?

```
  use Flow

  def run([stream]) do
    specs = [{{ProdCon,[]},[]}]
    consumer = [{{Consumer,[]},[]}]

    stream
    |> Flow.from_enumerable()
    |> Flow.through_specs(specs)
    |> Flow.into_specs(consumer)
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spawn a `Task` doing the job and wait until it finishes with [`Task.yield/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Task.html#yield/2):

```rb
use Flow

def run([stream]) do
  task = Task.async(fn ->

    specs = [{{ProdCon,[]},[]}]
    consumer = [{{Consumer,[]},[]}]

    stream
    |> Flow.from_enumerable()
    |> Flow.through_specs(specs)
    |> Flow.into_specs(consumer)

  end)

  case Task.yield(task, 3_600) do # wait 1 hour
    {:ok, result} -> result
    nil -> IO.puts("Failed to get a result :(")
  end
end
```

Comment: mmm is not working, doesnt do anything, all the use Flow and def run are defined in another module but dont think that changes anything

Comment: I am pretty sure the error is induced. The very same code works for me e.g. here: https://github.com/am-kantox/test_cluster_task/blob/master/lib/mix/tasks/test.cluster.ex.

Comment: mm might be different using Flow?

Comment: It’s very unlikely. Try to create the dummy application and run it instead of the pure `GenServer` maybe?

Comment: what I dont understand is which is the difference between running it through iex (where it works) and from command line mix task

Comment: `iex` starts a supervising process (for it’s own application,) what basically makes any running subtask to comfortably complete (app is running ⇒ ErlangVM is running ⇒ your code is running.)

Comment: mm should I wrap then stream  |> Flow.from_enumerable()  |> Flow.through_specs(specs)  |> Flow.into_specs(consumer) into a worker? maybe the way is done now GenServer.stop is being called before it's done

Comment: Indeed! Just [`Task.start_link/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Task.html#start_link/1) (or even `Task.async/1`) followed by `Task.yield/2` would be actually enough. I will update the answer.

Comment: actually it makes sense and it works for some simple task like writing in a file, but it keeps ignoring the Flow part, I think there must be something else to make it work with a Flow

Comment: I was able to find this for `Flow`: https://github.com/elixir-lang/flow/blob/v0.14.2/lib/flow.ex#L308-L325 so you might succeed by introducing a supervision tree and including the `Flow` into it.

Comment: I think both approachs, guard and task, would work for this, the issue is in my flow, I will accept the answer